# Jquery - This.Form Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, this

I am looking to submit the form of the button I am clicking on. Currently I have the following code:

```
$( "form.qsearch" ).submit(function(e) {...
```

This work perfect (in firebug i can see the GET running) as I am specifying the class of the form.  When I change this to this.form, nothing happens.  I no longer see anything happening in my firebug nor does the page load.  Does anyone know why it is recognizing form.qsearch but not this.form.  Is there another way to submit the "closest" form?  Thank you.

Just fyi, I am also trying to catch the var after the scrip runs...

```
$( "form.qsearch" ).submit(function(e) {

    Var Phone = $('#phone').val();
    ...
```

Comment: What are you expecting `this.form` to do? That's a selector for an element with the name `this` and a class of `form`: `<this class="form">`.

Comment: Im simply trying to submit the form using "this" or "closest" because i have a few forms on the page with the same id, name, class, etc., using a loop.

Comment: You cannot have multiple form with same id

Comment: Yes you should never use same id more than once if you not follow this you will make some big disaster later.

Comment: JavaScript is case-sensitive. You cannot use `Var` in place of `var` or `This` in place of `this`.

Comment: @user982853 Where is your loop? Why aren't you showing us any of the relevant code? Do you think we are mind readers?

Answer (score 0):

`this` refer to current scope object and by default it is window so to access your form you need to access it within document:

```
$(this.document.forms.formName)
```

and second case it is working as you directly hitting element with class and tagname.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to submit it via `this`, then you should have a parent container. Otherwise, your way is proper as it uses class name.

See, if this is what you are looking for and would like to use inside the loop.

```
$(this).find( "form" ).submit(function(e) {...
```